# RegEx not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer

OK, after searching high and low both here and on Google I have to bite the bullet and ask a new question here regarding RegEx in IE8.

I have the following code:

`var output = input.replace(/^\S+(\s|&nbsp;)+/, '');`

Its purpose is to remove currency names from amounts, so "kr 12 345,00" becomes "12 345,00" and "NOK 12 345,00" becomes "12 345,00" and so on.

This works fine everywhere except in Internet Explorer versions 8 or below, where *it leaves the input unchanged*.

Initially I was using the `new RegExp()` way of doing it, but changed it to the regular expression literal to see if there was a difference between how IE handled those two variations - which, thankfully, there wasn't :)

I have also tried with just the `\s` and with just the `&nbsp;` but that didn't make a difference.

The ***really*** weird thing is that when running the above regex with "kr 12 345,00" as the input on [W3 School's "Try It Yourself" page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_replace) in IE 8 it works fine! (also when the first space is substituted with `&nbsp;`)

So to reiterate: The place I'm seeing this issue is when using the regex in my Javascript code, which resides in an AngularJS filter function (I'm defining a filter), and the filter is returning the original input in IE8 (which is also seen with console.log() in IE8). Someone else tested it in IE9 for me, and reported that it worked fine there - and I have tested in Chrome as well. The only browsers in which I've encountered this issue are IE8 and IE7.

**What on earth is happening here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var output = input.replace(/^\S+([\s\xA0]|&nbsp;)+/, '');
```

According to [here](http://www.nivas.hr/blog/2012/01/19/non-breaking-white-space-in-internet-explorer-8-bug-and-how-to-fix-it/), "in IE8... \s (which should include all white space) doesn’t include non-breaking space".

Or better, just use

```
var output = input.replace( /^\D+/, '' );
```

where `\D` is any non-digit character.

Comment: I'll likely accept this tomorrow after I've checked it in IE at work. And thanks for the much simpler solution :) A long time since I've done any regex... That IE doesn't include the most common space character in the \s class is truly confounding.

Comment: It's really strange that my original regex works on the W3Schools page  in IE8 though.

Comment: I had heard about the IE8 non-breaking space bug before - but I guess I for some reason thought maybe the browser version of RegEx was supposed to include the character sequence "&nbsp;" in the \s class - which I certainly see isn't really very logical. I guess I just couldn't believe MS had missed including the most obvious character in that class :) Thanks for clearing it up for me though!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly as you're checking for `&nbsp;` I guess you're getting this value from the html (using `el.innerHTML` or `$(el).html()`. A better method, which converts all non-breaking whitespace into ' ' is to use `el.textContent` or `$(el).text()` (which also covers you for instances where e.g. the currency name is wrapped in a span (which possibly would have numbers in its attributes))

Then the following regex to replace all non digits at the start of the string

```
var output = input.replace(/^[^\d]+/, '');
```