# Javascript Regex IE8 issue

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer-8

I have a div as defined below:

```
<div id="bookmark_error" class="text-error">Character '' is not allowed in bookmark name.</div>
```

By default it is hidden as defined below:

```
$("#bookmark_error").hide();
```

Some of characters are not allowed while saving bookmark on a page for e.g. < and >

Here a validation check that is performed at the time of bookmark save:

```
...
var bookmark_name = $("#bookmarks-form").find('input[type=text]').val();
var skipChars = ["<", ">", "&lt;", "&gt;", "&lt", "&gt", "&#60;", "&#62;", "&#60", "&#62"];
                for (var i=0; i < skipChars.length; i++){
                    var skipChar = skipChars[i];
                    while(bookmark_name.indexOf(skipChar) != -1){
                        $("#bookmark_error").html($("#bookmark_error").html().replace(/'[^]*'/g, "'"+skipChar+"'"));
                        $("#bookmark_error").show();
                        return;
                    }
                }
...
```

But its not working as expected in IE8 browser.
Am I doing something wrong in javascript regex?

Here is some sample value-input-value:

value  : Character '' is not allowed in bookmark name.

input  : <

value : Character '<' is not allowed in bookmark name.

input  : >

output : Character '>' is not allowed in bookmark name.

Comment: Perhaps this will work fine `$("#bookmark_error").html($("#bookmark_error").html().replace(/'[^...]*'/g, "'"+skipChar+"'"));` Please verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `\d` in your regex for it to work on ie8

Reference from : [RegEx not working in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095862/regex-not-working-in-ie8)

So your code will look like this

```
$("#bookmark_error").html($("#bookmark_error").html().replace(/'[^\d]*'/g, "'"+skipChar+"'"));
```

Comment: what \d stands for in regex? Does it include < or > char?

Comment: A digit, just Google it.

Comment: `\d` stands for digit. check the reference link for for more info

Comment: What about < or > characters?

Comment: those are non-digit characters hence `^\d` is used

Comment: Can I say it simply any character including special characters, alphanumeric, digit also?

Comment: you will have to change the regex then. also that is a different question beyond the scope of the current question

Comment: my skip characters contains digits also as I mentioned in code `skipChars = ["<", ">", "&lt;", "&gt;", "&lt", "&gt", "&#60;", "&#62;", "&#60", "&#62"];`

Comment: those are not digits , those are html entities which translate to < and >